# Multiple apple account on the same mac wait 90 days to download?

Tags: itunes-store

So I have a US itunes account and a German one, because the US gets stuff earlier. The German one is my main account and I use that for the mac app store and for the apps on iTunes but I mainly use the US one for movies and TV shows.

I recently bought a movie from the German account, and when I tried to stream it on the mac, it told me that this computer is already associated with an Apple ID and after switching I have to wait 90 days.

So if my understanding is correct, if I opt to use my German account to download or stream the movie I just bought, I cannot access my stuff on the US account for the next 90 days, atleast not on this particular mac?

Was this always like that? I remember being able to switch back and fourth without a problem.

Answer (score -3):

it all has to de with media rights. some things that are available in 1 country do not necessarily have to be available in another country